# How can I use doc view in emacs -nw?

Tags: pdf, emacs, docview

Suppose I want to open the pdf file in the emacs. It is very easy in the emacs gui by using C-x C-f. But when I use it in emacs -nw. It shows the code instead of document. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Um… what do you expect to happen? How would a text-based terminal show PNG images?

Comment: @Chris So you mean it is impossible?

Comment: If you're using a traditional text-only terminal, and wanting to see the pages graphically, yes it's impossible. Have you ever seen images displayed in a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read the pdf as text you can dot it with pdf2txt and this function:

```
(defun open-pdf-in-txt (arg)
    (interactive "fpdf: ")
    (shell-command
     (format (concat "pdftotext " (replace-regexp-in-string " " "?\ " arg) " -layout")))
    (find-file (replace-regexp-in-string "pdf" "txt" arg)))
```